# Is it possible to set tool tip to title of JFace dialog

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created a custom Dialog which extends org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog. I'm Setting the title of the Dialog by overriding the configureShell method.

```java
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell shell)
{
    super.configureShell(shell);
    shell.setText("Parent \ Child \ Sub Child \ Sub Sub Child\ Sub Sub Sub child");
}
```

I have set the Initial size of the Dialog , so the text if exceeds the width of the Dialog , it displays the text till there and then followed by ...
Is it possible to increase the size of the tile bar?
Is it possible to add a tool tip to the text?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't set a tooltip or change the size.

The title bar is managed by the operating system window manager. The only things that can be specified in SWT are the title and the style bits when the shell is created.

You could also look at `TitleAreaDialog` which gives you an area at the top of the dialog for a more expansive title.